# Unable to locate Mix file: /assets/css/animate.css

Tags: laravel-8, assets, laravel-mix

I am hosting laravel into aws.I use public/assets/... folder for frontend. **webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/assets/js").postCss(
    "resources/css/app.css",
    "public/assets/css",
    [require("postcss-import"), require("tailwindcss")]
);
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change mix() to asset()